# Use Linksys WRT54G to get internet from Cisco E3000 (wifi) to Xbox (ethernet)?

Tags: wireless-networking, xbox360, wrt54g

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction...

I have a Cisco E3000 which is the main router for the house (WAN).

I want to use a WRT54G v8.2 to get Internet (from WiFi of the e3000) to my Xbox through the WRT Ethernet port. (Running a cable from the E3000 is impractical.)

Is this feasible? Do I need to flash a custom firmware? If so, which one is easiest to flash/set up?

[I was able to do this very easily with an Apple Airport Express which I no longer have access to ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DD-WRT is a 3rd party firmware that should allow you to create a wireless bridge to the E3000
Instructions for configuring the bridge can be found here:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged

Instructions for the WRT54G v8.2 can be found here:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54G_v7.2_%26_8.0_%26_v8.2#Gv8.0_.26_v8.2_.28see_below_for_v8.1.29